Number of ways of separating a finite set with linear hyperplanes.
I have the following question (3.3 (b)) from Foundations of Machine Learning by Mehryar Mohri (second edition).

3.3 (b). Let $\mathcal{X}=\{\mathbf{x}_1,\dots, \mathbf{x}_m\}$ be a subset of
$\mathbb{R}^d$ such that any $k$-element subset of $\mathcal{X}$ with
$k\leq d$ is linearly independent. Then, show that the number of
linearly separable labelings of $\mathcal{X}$ is $C(m,d) = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \binom{m-1}{k}$. (Hint: prove by induction that
$C(m+1,d)=C(m,d) + C(m,d-1)$).

In the context of the previous question, a linearly separable labeling of a set $\mathcal{X}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is a partition $\{\mathcal{X}^+,\mathcal{X}^-\}$ of $\mathcal{X}$ defined by $\mathcal{X}^+ = \{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{X}\colon \mathbb{w}\cdot\mathbb{x}>0\}$ and $\mathcal{X}^- = \{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{X}\colon \mathbb{w}\cdot\mathbb{x}<0\}$ for some $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^d$.
Using the fact that $\binom{m+1}{k} = \binom{m}{k} + \binom{m}{k-1}$, proving the hint was easy enough. My problem is that I can't figure out how to use this hint to prove the statement. My guess is that one is supposed to use induction over $m$ and, assuming for $m$, prove that the number of linear classifications for $m+1$ can be written as $C(m,d) 
 + C(m,d-1)$. I imagine that the idea is somewhat in the direction of fixing the label of $x_{m+1}$ and finding all possible linear classification (leading to $C(m,d)$) and then somehow show that the there are $C(m,d-1)$ unaccounted for linear classifications; I'm not sure how to do this.
I'm looking for hints, good hints, or a solution to the problem.
Thanks in advance.
Appendix:
Perhaps part (a) of the problem is of use.

3.3 (a) Let $\{\mathcal{X}^+, \mathcal{X}^-\}$ be a dichotomy of $\mathcal{X}$ and let $\mathbf{x}_{m+1}\in \mathbb{R}^d$. Show that $\{\mathcal{X}^+\cup\{\mathbf{x}_{m+1}\},\mathcal{X}^-\}$ and $\{\mathcal{X}^+,\mathcal{X}^-\cup\{\mathbf{x}_{m+1}\}\}$ are linearly separable by a hyperplane going through the origin if and only if $\{\mathcal{X}^+,\mathcal{X}^-\}$ is linearly separable by a hyperplane going through the origin and $\mathbf{x}_{m+1}$.


The proof is provided in great detail in Information theory, Inference and Learning Algorithms by  David J. C. MacKay, Chapter 40. By the way, the factor of 2 is due to the fact that you can always reverse the labels by multiplying $\bf w$ with -1.

$\def\cX{\mathcal{X}}$
$\def\cS{\mathcal{S}}$
$\def\bx{{\bf x}}$
$\def\bw{{\bf w}}$
$\def\R{\mathbb{R}}$
$\def\N{\mathbb{N}}$
$\def\qty#1{\left(#1\right)}$
$\def\be{{\bf e}}$
The way the authors of the book set up the problem produces a more linear proof.
(a) Let $\{\cX^+,\cX^-\}$ be a dichotomy of $\cX$ and let ${\bf x}_{m+1}\in \R^d$. Show that $\{\cX^+ \cup \{\bx_{m+1}\},\cX^-\}$ and $\{\cX^+ ,\cX^- \cup \{\bx_{m+1}\}\}$ are linearly separable by a hyperplane going though the origin if and only if $\{\cX^+,\cX^-\}$ is linearly separable by a hyperplane going through the origin and $\bx_{m+1}$.
Note that a corollary of (a) is that if $\bx_{m+1}$ is not on the hyperplane then either $\bw\cdot\bx_{m+1}>0$ or $\bw\cdot\bx_{m+1}<0$. Therefore either $\{\cX^+ \cup \{\bx_{m+1}\},\cX^-\}$ or $\{\cX^+ ,\cX^- \cup \{\bx_{m+1}\}\}$ are linearly separable. So the existing weight vector classifies $\bx_{m+1}$ and no new labels (weight vectors) can be generated.
(b) Let $\cX = \{\bx_1,\ldots,\bx_m \}$ be a subset of $\R^d$ such that any $k$-element subset of $\cX$ with $k \leq d$ is linearly independent. Then, show that the number of linearly separable labelings of $\cX$ is $C(m,d)=2\sum_{k=1}^{d-1}\binom{m-1}{k}$.
Start with $\cX$ and $C(m,d)$ labels. Add a new point $\bx_{m+1}$ to obtain $C(m+1,d)$ labels. Before adding the new point we obtained the $C(m,d)$ labels by varying $\bw$ so that for some $\bx_p \in \cX$ we had $\bx_p \in \cX^+(\bw)$ and for some $\bx_n \in \cX$ we had $\bx_n \in \cX^-(\bw)$. For $N$ of those weight vectors the new point $\bx_{m+1}$ was on the hyperplane, so we are able to derive $2N$ new linearly separable labelings as we have shown in (a). For the rest, $C(m,d)-N$ we generate the same number of labels as before since the existing weight vectors can classify the new point. Therefore
$$
C(m+1,d)=C(m,d)-N + 2N = C(m,d)+N.
$$
To derive $N$ use an orthonormal basis with $\be_1=\frac{\bx_{m+1}}{\lVert \bx_{m+1} \rVert}$. Then any $\bw$ we choose must have the property $w^1=0$ so that $\bw \cdot \bx_{m+1}=0$. This means for any vector $\bx \in \R^d$ the first component $x^1$ has no effect on the sign of $\bw \cdot \bx$. So effectively we are using the projections of the vectors in the subspace spanned by $\be_2,\ldots,\be_d$. Since the dimension of this subspace is $d-1$ we can generate $C(m,d-1)$ linearly separable labelings and so $N=C(m,d-1)$. Therefore the recursive formula is
$$
C(m+1,d)=C(m,d)+C(m,d-1).  \tag{R} 
$$
We can try to reduce it to an expression that contains $C(m',1)$ which is equal to 2 (in one dimension we have positive and/or negative numbers so we can only get two labels) or $C(1,d')$ which is also equal to 2 (if a single vector $\bx$ has $\bw\cdot\bx>0$ then we can use $\bw'=-\bw$ to obtain a second label). So starting with $C(m,d)$ use ($\text{R}$) to write
$$
C(m,d)=C(m-1,d)+C(m-1,d-1).
$$
Using ($\text{R}$) for $C(m-1,d)$ and $C(m-1,d-1)$ we have
\begin{align}
C(m,d)&=C(m-2,d)+C(m-2,d-1)+C(m-2,d-1)+C(m-2,d-2) \\
&=C(m-2,d) + 2 C(m-2,d-1)+ C(m-2,d-2).
\end{align}
Note that the coefficients are $\binom{2}{0},\binom{2}{1}$ and $\binom{2}{2}$. Next we can write
\begin{align}
C(m,d)& =C(m-3,d)+C(m-3,d-1)+2\qty{C(m-3,d-1)+C(m-3,d-2)}+C(m-3,d-2)+C(m-3,d-3)\\
& = C(m-3,d) + 3 C(m-3,d-1) + 3 C(m-3,d-2) + C(m-3,d-3) \\
& = \binom{3}{0} C(m-3,d) + \binom{3}{1} C(m-3,d-1) + \binom{3}{2} C(m-3,d-2) + \binom{3}{3} C(m-3,d-3).
\end{align}
From this pattern it is clear that
$$
C(m,d)=\binom{m-1}{0}C(1,d)+\binom{m-1}{1}C(1,d-1)+\binom{m-1}{2}C(1,d-2)+\ldots+
\binom{m-1}{m-3}C(1,d-(m-3))
+\binom{m-1}{m-2}C(1,d-(m-2))+
\binom{m-1}{m-1}C(1,d-(m-1)).
$$
If $d-k<1$ then $C(1,d-k)=0$ (we can only generate labels for $d-k\in \N$). Therefore the last expression can be reduced to
$$
C(m,d)  = \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \binom{m-1}{k} C(1,d-k) = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \binom{m-1}{k}.
$$
